Did Kurt Gödel say this quote about materialism?
In an interview, David Berlinski mentioned Kurt Gödel's view on materialism. He said:

Materialism succeeds to the extent that the materialists assigned to
material objects all the properties that used to be assigned to
non-material objects to the extent it is infinitely flexible.

Obviously, it is possible he rephrased it or translated it from Gödel's original phrasing. Either way, my Google search did not come up with anything useful. Did Gödel make such a remark?

Crosspost from Philosophy.SE.  Which is fine in a case when the question is on topic for both sites, but you should make sure each question contains a link to the other.
